# What are the requirements for support of extended length APDUs and which smartphones support it?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

When I first tried to send an APDU command and got the "Above supported length" error, I assumed that is just a limitation of the NFC chip itself -  no way around it. However [this site](https://www.openecard.org/en/ecard-api-framework/extended-length-problem/) suggests that it might be a software problem in the Android OS instead:

> many currently available smartphones are only able to transmit 261 Bytes[2] via NFC without major modifications **of the operating system**.

Does anyone know more about how to get get around this problem and how "major" exactly the modifications are?

Also, do you have a list, which phones support extended length APDU? If not, we should probably start one, as you really don't find much on google.

I know that the Samsung Galaxy Note II supports it, while Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus 5 and Galaxy Nexus don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this site:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76598

What you have to do:

- Download the Android Sources
- Change "261" to "2462" in the line in NativeNfcManager.java (as shown on the site linked above)
- Build Android
- Flash your modified Android version on the phone

A tutorial for building Android for Nexus 5 can be found here:
http://nosemaj.org/howto-build-android-kitkat-nexus-5

This works for the reader mode of your smartphone, I do not know yet how to get it to work for the card emulation mode.

Answer (score 1):

A better/easier/more portable solution is to only send 261 Bytes (or less) and returning the ISO7816-4 status codes SW1-SW2 = 0x61xx with xx telling the number of data bytes still available.
The reader will send the ISO7816-4 command 'GET RESPONSE' to request the remaining bytes.

For instance, if you want to send 300 bytes from Android HCE, then you will start to reply:

1. HCE: `sendResponseApdu({ 250 first bytes of data + 0x6132 })` (0x32 means 50 remaining bytes)
2. NFC Card reader should send: `GET RESPONSE`
3. HCE: `sendResponseApdu({ last 50 bytes of data + 0x9000 })`

Comment: Is this approach working? Are you tried your solution?